# how to do lookup from one dataframe to another in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, lookup, apache-spark-dataset

I am having three dataframes in spark and want to extract value from one dataframe to another two on basis of some condition. Below is the scenario which I am having. Can someone help me here.

DF1:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#aaa;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#333;background-color:#fff;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#fff;background-color:#f38630;}
.tg .tg-j2zy{background-color:#FCFBE3;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-baqh{text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-yq6s{background-color:#FCFBE3;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-baqh">person_id</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">criterion_name_1</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">criterion_id_1</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">criterion_name_2</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">criterion_id_2</th>
    <th class="tg-baqh">criterion_name_3</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">criterion_id_3</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">criterion_name_4</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">criterion_id_4</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">criterion_name_5</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">criterion_id_5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yq6s">100</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">Condition</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">A-363-3015</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">null</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">null</td>
    <td class="tg-yq6s">null</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">null</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">null</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">null</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">null</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">101</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Condition</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">D-229-3007</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Condition</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">A-229-3008</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Condition</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">D-229-3008</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Condition</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">A-229-3009</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Condition</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">D-229-3009</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yq6s">102</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">Condition</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">A-229-3012</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">Observation</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">PZXC</td>
    <td class="tg-yq6s">null</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">null</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">null</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">null</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">null</td>
    <td class="tg-j2zy">null</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Apart from this DF I am having 2 more lookup dataframes 1. condition DF and 2. observation DF

1. Condition DF:

   ```
   +-----+--------------+------+
   | id  | condition_id | code |
   +-----+--------------+------+
   | 100 | A-363-3015   | xyz  |
   +-----+--------------+------+
   | 101 | A-334-3015   | pqr  |
   +-----+--------------+------+
   ```
2. observation DF:

> ```
> +-----+----------------+------+
> | id  | observation_id | code |
> +-----+----------------+------+
> | 100 | PZXC           | 123  |
> +-----+----------------+------+
> | 101 | P2WZX          | pw32 |
> +-----+----------------+------+
> ```

I want the final DF with below structure and the value will come on this DF from lookup DFs.

```
|person_id|criterion_name_1|criterion_id_1|criterion_value_1|criterion_name_2|criterion_id_2|criterion_value_2|criterion_name_3|criterion_id_3|criterion_value_3|criterion_name_4|criterion_id_4|criterion_value_4|criterion_name_5|criterion_id_5|criterion_value_5|
```

in the above DF structure value of Column criterion_value_1,criterion_value_2, criterion_value_3..... criterion_value_5 will come on below condition.

if `criterion_name_1 = condition` then it will lookup into condition DF and match value od `criterion_id_1` with condition_code column of condition DF and get the value of code column in `criterion_value_1` column and it will do it for all the corresponding `criterion_name` upto 5.

Same will be applicable for if `criterion_name_1` = observation with observation lookup DF.

Comment: How big are the condition and observation dataframes? Is it practical to perform a search of them for every person? If that's the case, and both observation and condition return the same type of data (presumably strings) you could achieve this via a UDF that returns a string, and takes a criterion name + ID.
Alternatively, do observation and condition share any keys? If not, you can ignore this by having a single lookup table because it doesn't matter which it's from. In this case, key refers to the 'code' field

Comment: Can you please provide example of lookup ?

Comment: It would just be combining the observation and condition table into a single table.

Comment: Ehm, the concept of a "lookup DF" is plain wrong. DataFrames are used for large dataset and they are not suited for lookups. So if the data in these "lookup DFs" you mention are small enough to fit into a normal `HashMap`, you should use that instead of converting it into a DF. If there is indeed a need for a DF, then you have to shake off the idea of doing lookups and instead use `join`.